# PHP sessions on localhost using xampp

Tags: php, session, xampp, localhost

I run xampp 1.7.3 on my local windows xp pc.
A phpinfo() confirms that sessions are enabled.

In a 'login.php' I have to following code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = "user";
//var_dump($_SESSION);
header("Location: index.php");
```

In the 'index.php' I have this code:

```
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

However, nothing is printed when I get to index.php, the $_SESSION information seems to be lost (because it is printed when I uncomment the var_dump in login.php). In the php.ini I checked the session.save_path. In this path I can find a session file that contains the session information stored in login.php. But why is the session information not carried over to index.php?? Is this for some reason because i'm running on localhost?

Comment: Do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: As Truth already mentioned, make sure you can see all errors and warnings `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and make sure that your browser is allowed to store cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. Error reporting is enabled (error_reporting(E_ALL);) and the browser too is allowed to store cookies.

Comment: Try looking at the http stream with fiddler / iehttpheaders / tamperdata / firebug to check the cookie is being set / returned.

Comment: Does the session-id change between the pages, or does it remain constant (you can check the id with `session_id()`)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this will work because for $_SESSION to work, headers need to be set.

By setting the header() in the middle of the script, your are preventing the $_SESSION from being fully applied.

So don't use header() to change location to the index.php. You could put a link on login.php, click that to go to index.php, and see that your session has been properly configured.

*You could also use JavaScript to change the page after it loads, just don't use PHP header().*

Comment: A redirect works without problems, i implemented a Post-Redirect-Get pattern this way on my site. Normally you add an `exit();` just after the redirect, otherwise the script continues to run anyway.